# What would be the appropriate site to use to ask a question related to the language Processing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

**I would like to know what the appropriate Stack Exchange site to ask questions related to the Processing would be.**

I'm referring to *Processing,* the Java-based visualization language — see http://www.processing.org/. It has its own forums, but they're not as good as Stack Exchange, naturally. =)

[*Having had a bad experience with a moderator moving posts to tumbleweed-land*](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1577/possible-to-protest-the-transfer-of-a-question-to-another-forum) forums based on dubious interpretations of the not-very-effectively-descriptive "FAQ" section for each of these different Stack Exchange sites, I'd like an answer about where these questions should go first, so I can't be lectured about not reading the About page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a StackOverflow question for me...

> Processing is an *open source programming language* and environment for people who want to create images, animations, and interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Just ask it on whatever website you feel would be the best fit; the worst that can happen is it will get moved.

A question getting moved is not really a big deal - it happens hundreds of times a day - so please don't make it one like last time.